# grep for path separator

Tags: grep

I have some code which has Windows path separator hard-coded all over it.

```
blah + '\\' + blah
```

I've been trying to find them with

```
grep -FR "\\\\" *.py
grep -ER "^(.+?)\\\\" *.py
```

which are obvious failures. What should the expression be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

grep -FR '\\' *.py

does work in my environment (tested)

The -F indicates fixed string, and only 2 slashes are needed to match 2 slashes in your file.

I hope this helps.

Comment: @shelter: when I do grep -FR '\\' *, I get all the results including the py~ .. but grep -FR '\\' *.py does not give anything!

Comment: @Tathagata : if all your files are named ending in py~, then you need to specify that as the file target like `grep -FR'\\' *.py~` OR use a wild card instead `grep -FR'\\' *.py*` .... OR do I not understand your comment? Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

\ is the escape character, so to get a \, you use \\, and to get \\, you use \\\\

```
foo@bar: ~ > cat test 
blah + '\\' + blah
foo@bar: ~ > grep '\\\\' test 
blah + '\\' + blah
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
grep '\\\\' *.py
```

if you want to grab 2 slashes